Enable OpenMp during vcpkg build
Hello I am building mpfr by doing
.\vcpkg.exe install mpfr:x64-windows-release
I am not using the original sources that were defined inside portfile.cmake, but rather one updated variant of mine which is packaged into the original tar.xz. (Some files are updated)
#vcpkg_download_distfile(ARCHIVE
#    URLS "http://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-${VERSION}/mpfr-${VERSION}.tar.xz" "https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/mpfr/mpfr-${VERSION}.tar.xz"
#    FILENAME "mpfr-${VERSION}.tar.xz"
#    SHA512 bc68c0d755d5446403644833ecbb07e37360beca45f474297b5d5c40926df1efc3e2067eecffdf253f946288bcca39ca89b0613f545d46a9e767d1d4cf358475
#)*/

vcpkg_download_distfile(ARCHIVE
    OUT_SOURCE_PATH SOURCE_PATH
    URLS "file:///C:/cygwin64/home/ckalonak/mpfr-4.2.1.tar.xz"
    FILENAME "mpfr-4.2.1.tar.xz"
    SHA512 "2760afad0dbbc098e1d23786dae0d96474355e4dd5d11b9583af0a2d867ab7bede33c697bc68eb29834c24d41e8f7b6a95807fbb17fbea57e2fb2de9a0a8abdd"
)

On this updated code I have some openmp directives so I want to somehow force
vcpkg_configure_make(
    SOURCE_PATH "${SOURCE_PATH}"
    AUTOCONFIG
)

To configure the build in order to use openmp and then build it using:
vcpkg_install_make()

I have tried to find a way to do it for hours, and ChatGPT is hallucinating like hell!
Anyone has any ideas of how to make the build use the openmp directives?
